# Why is the IntalliTrace option greyed-out when publishing to Azure?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I've got VS2010 Ultimate and a single Azure role (granted, it's dependant on a lot of other, smaller projects).

When trying to deploy it, the option to enable IntelliTrace is greyed-out. All of the projects are .NET 4.0 projects, so as far as I can tell, this shouldn't be happening.

Please help.

Comment: Options like that are not disabled by accident.  There's code in Visual Studio that does the "nope, can't do that yet" intentionally.  Losing functionality when you only have a wire into a cloud is to be expected, post feature requests to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running on a 32 bit machine? You need [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB983301) to enable Intellitrace on non-64 bits machines.

Comment: Yes, I AM running this on a 32bit machine. I'll give this a go. I really should reinstall Windows one of these days. ;)

Comment: BUT I've also went ahead and installed SP1 for VS2010, and that seemed to have worked. :)